# SPNavigationNode.IsVisible property not working in sharepoint as expected

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

I want to hide a quick launch node in a sharepoint site, but it's not working as expected. :(

My code is as under:

```
                using (SPSite spSiteTest = new SPSite(serverUrl))
                {

                    using (SPWeb mySite = spSiteTest.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPNavigationNodeCollection quickLaunchNodes = mySite.Navigation.QuickLaunch;

                    SPNavigationNode navQuickNode = new SPNavigationNode("Title", "www.stackoverflow.com", true);


                    foreach (SPNavigationNode node in quickLaunchNodes)
                    {
                        if (node.Title == navQuickNode.Title)
                        {
                            node.Url = navQuickNode.Url;
                            node.IsVisible = isVisible;
                            node.Update();
                            //mySite.Update();
                            return;
                        }
                    }   

                    quickLaunchNodes.AddAsFirst(navQuickNode);

                }
            }
```

Am I missing something or is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the nodes like this:

```
node.Delete();
mySite.Update();
```

or check the `ExcludeFromNavigation` method mentioned in [this post](http://blogs.pointbridge.com/Blogs/shah_talha/Pages/Post.aspx?_ID=11) (its author suggests that not being able to hide a navigation node by setting `IsVisible` to `false` is a SharePoint bug, too).

Answer (score 0):

### How to show/hide navigation nodes using SharePoint Server Side Object Model (SSOM)

[PortalNavigation Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.navigation.portalnavigation(v=office.14).aspx) exposes the following methods for that purpose:

- [PortalNavigation.ExcludeFromNavigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.navigation.portalnavigation.excludefromnavigation(v=office.14).aspx) - explicitly excludes a
  specific subsite or page from being displayed in navigation
- [PortalNavigation.IncludeInNavigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.navigation.portalnavigation.includeinnavigation(v=office.14).aspx) - Explicitly includes a
  specific subsite or page for display in navigation

**Examples**

How to hide site from Current navigation:

```
using (var site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
{
    using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        var subWeb = web.Webs["Announcements"];

        var publishingWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);
        publishingWeb.Navigation.ExcludeFromNavigation(false,subWeb.ID);
        publishingWeb.Update();

    }
}
```

### How to show/hide navigation nodes using SharePoint Client Side Object Model (CSOM)

It is not supported to modify navigation settings via SharePoint CSOM.

Regarding SharePoint **2013**:

> In SharePoint 2013 was introduced a new
>   [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.publishing(v=office.15).aspx) and
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.Navigation namespaces in CSOM
>   API. But unfortunately it is not supported to modify navigation
>   settings using [WebNavigationSettings class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.publishing.navigation.webnavigationsettings(v=office.15).aspx) since properties are
>   exposes as a *read-only*.

For CSOM, you could utilize the [ClientPortalNavigation.cs class](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/7090347) that represents a CSOM counterpart for SSOM PortalNavigation Class. Follow [Access and Manipulate Navigation Settings via SharePoint Client Object Model](http://blog.vgrem.com/2013/10/22/access-and-manipulate-navigation-settings-via-sharepoint-client-object-model/) post for more details.

**Examples**

How to hide a page from Global navigation:

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{

     //Get page file
     var pageFile = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/news/Pages/Announcements.aspx");
     ctx.Load(pageFile);
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();

     //Hide page from Global navigation
     var navigation = new ClientPortalNavigation(ctx.Web);
     navigation.ExcludeFromNavigation(true, pageFile.UniqueId);
     navigation.SaveChanges();
 }
```

How to hide a site from Global navigation:

```
 using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
 {

     //Get sub site
     var result = ctx.LoadQuery(ctx.Web.Webs.Where(w => w.Title == "Archive"));
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();
     var subWeb = result.FirstOrDefault();

     //Hide web from Global navigation
     var navigation = new ClientPortalNavigation(ctx.Web);
     navigation.ExcludeFromNavigation(true, subWeb.Id);
     navigation.SaveChanges();
 }
```